# SAGA Maximum Flow Length problems with the Coordinate systems

Tags: raster, saga, hydrology, rivers

I'm new to SAGA.

I've got a srtm data set from europe and want to charge the maximum flow length especially from the river Elbe. The data is in WGS84
So first I ran the tool "Fill Sinks"(Wang & Liu) and the flow length downstream but the output flow length were in degree. So I transformed my original data in another coordinate system (I've tried EPSG 4087, 32662 and 54031) with meters as unit and ran the same tools but the watersheds and the flow length looks really creepy in those cases.

Also I have no clue what the "maximum slope legth" in the "Fill sinks" tool stands for.

Comment: How about UTM zone 32 (EPSG:32632)? SAGA has a handy `UTM Projection (Grid)` tool. About the *creepy* output, changing *Resampling* method may help. (Please try bi-cubic).

Comment: I've cosen those coordinate systems because I have to do the same procedures with a world Dataset. The Elbe is only a testing area for me. So the UTM zones are not really helpful in this case. I will try to change the Resampling method thanks.

Comment: I've tried Nearest Neighbour and Bicubic resampling but the results are nearly the same. Its like the water flows straight from the middle of europe to the coasts. https://goo.gl/gByYRg